# EF Core inherited CachedRepository throws System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, service, entity-framework-core, background-service

I have Service that makes use of a service/repository-pattern. Some but not all repositories inherit from a CachedRepository. Since I have a lot of repositories that make use of caching I did not want to go with a decorator pattern.
The cache works fine. But when it handles more than one request then more often then not it will throw this exception:

`System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.`

All the repositories and the services that make use of them are dependency injected with a Scoped ServiceLifetime. A repository might be used by multiple services.

```cs
public class CachedRepository
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache cache;

    const int expirationTime = 20;

    public CachedRepository(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    protected async Task<T> GetCacheItem<T>(Task<T> fetchData, string key, int expirationMinutes = expirationTime)
    {
        string cacheKey = $"{key}";

        if (cache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out T cacheItem))
        {
            return cacheItem;
        }
        
        cacheItem = await fetchData;

        var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

        cache.Set(cacheKey, cacheItem, now.AddMinutes(expirationMinutes));
        return cacheItem;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class SomeEntityRepository : CachedRepository
{
    private readonly SomeContext context;
    private readonly string repoName;

    public SomeEntityRepository (SomeContext context, IMemoryCache cache) : base(cache)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.repoName = GetType().FullName;
    }


    public async Task<SomeEntity> GetSomeEntity(int id)
    {
        const string methodName = nameof(GetSomeEntity);
        string cacheKey = $"{repoName}_{methodName}_{id.ToString()}";


        Task<SomeEntity> func(int i) => context.SomeEntities
                                                 .AsNoTracking()
                                                 .Where(x=> x.Id == i)
                                                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return await GetCacheItem(func(id), cacheKey);
    }
}
```

I've tried the following:

- Adding locks/semaphores/mutexes to the cached repository before fetchdata and free ressource after.
- Changed Task in method to be async/await.
- Changed Task in method to be a Func<Task>>
- Set query tracking behavior on context to be NoTracking as default
- Set ServiceLifetime on context to be Transient
- Triple checked that await is used everywhere the context is accessed

Comment: This is a misuse of EF Core, and all attempts to "fix" it only make things worse. The exception itself isn't about caching at all, but trying to use the Unit-of-Work from multiple threads. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection, and already caches the objects it loads by PK. The question's code *disabled* caching by using `AsNoTracking()`. Since it's a Unit-of-Work, it makes *no* sense to reuse it among threads. The Unit-of-Work will detect and persist all changes by itself when `SaveChanges` is called, in a single database transaction.

Comment: EF Core neither has nor needs a low-level, single-type "repository" anyway, it's a higher-level multi-entity abstraction. We can only guess what the project's "repository" classes do. In many similar questions they aren't repositories at all but Data-Access Object classes with just CRUD methods.  In many such cases, transactions are completely broken by calling `SaveChanges` after every single CUD call. In other cases, `Update` is called on tracked objects for no reason at all - the UoW already detects changes. Quite often the extra Update or Add calls result in duplicate entries and conflicts

Comment: `make use of caching` why, where and how do you use caching? You wouldn't have this exception in a controller action, because the scope is the individual request. Are you using the "repository" in a BackgroundService? In that case the "scope" is the hosted service's lifetime, same as the application. [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) explains how to use scoped services in this case

Comment: Or is this a Blazor Server project? The problem is similar - in Blazor Server, the scope is the user's session (circuit). [ASP.NET Core Blazor with Entity Framework Core (EF Core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-8.0) shows how to handle scoped services and even scope to a component's lifecycle, in this case.

Comment: It is used in a BackgroundService that consumes messages from a MQ. The data that is cached is not something that the service make changes to. The service never handles more than one message at a time from the queue.

Comment: That means two things: 1) you need to explicitly manage either the scope or the DbContext, as both links show and 2) you don't need that CachedRepository at all. The primary data container is the lookup cache that just happens to load data from another API, EF, Dapper or a CSV file. The entire owner/inheritance relation is upside-down. Your BackgroundService only needs to know about some `ILookupService<T>`, not what it uses to reload data, or even what's used to cache it (IDistributedMemoryCache? IMemoryCache? ConcurrentDictionary<> ?)

Comment: BTW you should use [GetOrCreateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.getorcreateasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) instead of `TryGet/Set`. Any connections or contexts should be created and disposed inside the async factory method.

Comment: So there are two ways to fix my issues. One was to pass the context down to the `CachedRepository`class. But that would defeat the thing I was trying to do. The other was to move the caching to the `SomeEntityRepository` and here I used `GetOrCreateAsync` instead. This is a solution I am satisfied with as `CachedRepository` only existed in order to reduce the amount of duplicated code.

Comment: The real issue is that two independent concepts, caching and data loading, where tightly-coupled by CachedRepository. You don't need extra code if you have a LookupService<T> that uses some other injected service to load its data. The lookup service has a completely different lifecycle than the loading code too.